# Remove part of URL using Mod_Rewrite with #

Tags: javascript, regex, apache, redirect, mod-rewrite

So I'm trying to use this:

`RewriteRule (.*)/#!/(.*) $1/$2 [R,L]`

My goal is to re-write and redirect `http://blog.domain/#!/category/post` to `http://blog.domain/category/post`

The reason is, the WP theme I use has a jquery slider that inserts the #! and when that is present in the URL, some of the pages I have that have "auto inserted code" is missing the url (remove the #! and it works fine).

Any clues? I need the browser URL to read `http://blog.domain/category/post` when finished.

Answer (score 0):

This obviously cannot be handled in .htaccess or any other server side tool since any browser will not send URI part after hash `#` to server.

What you can do is to include this Javascript ib your page for this redirect:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   if (location.href.indexOf("#") > -1) {
       location.assign(location.href.replace(/#!\/?/, ""));
   }
</script>
```